# Unexpected offset when using a ConfigurableJoint to manipulate object's rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, quaternions, physx

I'm trying to use a `ConfigurableJoint` (based on Nvidia's 9xD6Joint) to manipulate a `Rigidbody` the player is holding. I have an issue with setting the spring part of the joint correctly. This is how the joint I'm using is configured:

```
_joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
_joint.connectedAnchor = Vector3.zero;
_joint.enableCollision = true;
_joint.rotationDriveMode = RotationDriveMode.Slerp; // using slerp rotation
_joint.xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
_joint.yMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
_joint.zMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
_joint.angularXMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
_joint.angularYMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
_joint.angularZMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
```

Here is how I try to set the target rotation of the joint:

```
var playerRotation = transform.rotation;
var targetRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(playerRotation) * _targetRotation;
_joint.targetRotation = _targetRotation;
```

`_targetRotation` is the rotation I'm trying to achieve, in world space.

The problem is that the rotation of the connected body doesn't match up with the `_targetRotation`. There is always some offset, that rotates the connected body at an angle relative to the `_targetRotation`. Once connected the offset stays consistent. What's even more confusing to me is that the offset seems to be based on the initial rotation of the connected body. This means that the same `_targetRotation` will result in different connected body rotation if the connected body's rotation was different when connecting it to the joint.

Also the multiplication by `Quaternion.Inverse(playerRotation)` is there only to make the rotation relative to the player, but the same problem occurs when this step is ommited.

Answer (score 0):

`_joint.targetRotation` is relative to the joint local space (defined by its `axis` and `secondaryAxis`) and to the initial rotation of the target `RigidBody` when the joint is created.

See this link to a detailed answer to how to deal with that : https://answers.unity.com/questions/278147/how-to-use-target-rotation-on-a-configurable-joint.html